# How to check if object belongs to an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I usually have to check things like:

`if ['Bob','Mary','John'].include? @user.name`

Is there a way to write something like:

`if @user.name.in? ['Bob','Mary','John']`

Thank you.

Comment: Could you tell why the first line does not suit you? Or do you simply want to know a different way of achieving the same?

Comment: I think the first way is not natural (something Ruby wants to avoid).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails 3.1 has got this `Object.in?` method

```
characters = ["Konata", "Kagami", "Tsukasa"]
"Konata".in?(characters) # => true

character = "Konata"
character.in?("Konata", "Kagami", "Tsukasa") # => true
```

Answer (score 4):

If `@user.name` is a `String`, you can add `in?` to `String`.

```
class String                                                                                                                                                          
  def in? a
    a.include? self
  end
end
```

This has the following effect:

```
irb(main):011:0> 'Bob'.in? ['Bob','Mary','John']
=> true
irb(main):012:0> 'Jane'.in? ['Bob','Mary','John']
=> false
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that Rails have a miracle method to do this for any class, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @phogratos: Why do you restrict your solution to `String`? You may add it to `Object`. Then you could use `6.in?( [1,2,] )`.  Or is `in?` part of another object?

Comment: @knut: Indeed you can extend Object as well, but you can never be sure if `in?` is used anywhere else. So I suggest restricting monkey patching to specific classes.